# stripos Not working

Tags: php, irc

I have the file set so that it has the usernames like so

> Name1
>
> Name2
>
> Name3

```
$tuser = implode(" ", $this->arguments);
$line = file("tready.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$line_check = implode(" ", $line);
$search_string = $tuser;

if (!empty($tuser)) {
  if (stripos($line_check, $search_string) !== FALSE) {
    $this->say('Your already on the list!');
  } else {
    file_put_contents("tready.txt", $tuser, FILE_APPEND);
    $this->say('Your team has been added to the list: ' . $tuser);
  }
} else {
  $this->say('Invalid Entry. !Addme [username]');
}
```

What its not doing is this:

```
if (stripos($line_check, $search_string) !== FALSE)
```

I have check the $line_check and $search_string on an echo prior to the script running and they show up correctly but when it comes to having them check against themselves somethings not working properly and it allows the script to add them anyway. Am I using the wrong procedures?

Comment: Why do all the string shenanigans when you can use file() and match with [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using [array_search()](https://www.php.net/array_search), which makes it much easier to match the string against the array.

```
$tuser = implode(" ", $this->arguments);
$line  = file("tready.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

if (!empty($tuser)) {
  if (array_search($tuser, $line) !== FALSE) {
    $this->say('Your already on the list!');
  } else {
    file_put_contents("tready.txt", $tuser, FILE_APPEND);
    $this->say('Your team has been added to the list: ' . htmlentities($tuser));
  }
} else {
  $this->say('Invalid Entry. !Addme [username]');
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean by "just check/add as-is" I need the data to be pulled from the command, $tuser cannot be a static phrase.

Comment: as long as $tuser ends up as a string its ok. `$tuser = implode(" ", $this->arguments);` no need to re-assign

Comment: Oh IC yeah I was just doing that to run a check there was really no functional purpose to doing that. Unfortunately the code is still skipping over the check and still adding the string to the file.

Comment: Nevermind that made a who new issue, now its not adding it to a new line :(

Comment: if you want a new line then add one `file_put_contents("tready.txt", $tuser.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);` so append PHP_EOL or `"\n\n"` to the string